# Dual boot (Win7+Ubuntu14) fails for Win 7 after adding SSD with Ubuntu 16

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, uefi, ssd, grubrescue

I have an ASUS laptop with HDD and dual boot via grub2: Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.

When after 5 years HDD started failing with bad blocks I added SSD to SATA port 2. I made SSD a single boot Ubuntu 16 with its own EFI partition - so as to remove HDD one day when it fails completely and to proceed with SSD only.

I partitioned SSD manually when installing Ubuntu 16 on it from Live USB: picked "Something else" in install dialog, took care to mount `/boot/efi`, `/boot`, `/` and `/home` to SSD partitions I've just created from Live USB and checked that HDD partitions are in "Do not use this partition".

Unfortunately, I didn't check the EFI partition on HDD. So despite specifying sdb1 (/boot/efi of SSD) as `Use as: EFI System Partition` and despite selecting /dev/sdb (SSD) as a `Device for boot loader installation`, bootloaders ended up at HDD, not at SSD as I planned it. This is because EFI partition on HDD was also left configured as `Use as: EFI System Partition`.

The 2 resulting problems are:

1. ESP (EFI) is on HDD, not on SSD.
2. Windows 7 falls into grub rescue, while both Ubuntu 16 and Ubuntu 14 boot fine. I wonder if the 2 problems are related.

To solve problem 1, I copied the contents of HDD's EFI to SSD's EFI and changed `/boot/efi` mapping in `/etc/fstab` to point to SSD's EFI (`UUID=E2A1-9FFE`, `/dev/sdb1`):

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=40BE-2040  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# redirecting /boot/efi from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdb1
UUID=E2A1-9FFE  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

Now the correct EFI partition (on SSD) gets mounted to `/boot/efi` when Ubuntu boots (although I didn't check if the correct EFI gets used **during** booting). **Is it OK** to solve problem 1 this way: by copying files + changing fstab?

And **how do I solve Problem 2**? When picking `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)` in grub, I see this error and this config from `set`:

```
error: symbol `grub_term_highlight_color` not found.
grub rescue> set
lang=
locale_dir=
prefix=(hd0,gpt6)/grub
root=hd0,gpt6
secondary_locale_dir=
```

When picking `Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)` in grub, I see this error and this config from `set`:

```
error: file `/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod` not found.
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd1,gpt6)/grub
root=hd1,gpt6
```

In BIOS (UEFI) the boot devices are called, respectively:

```
Windows Boot Manager (P0: ST1000...)
Windows Boot Manager (P1: Samsung SSD 850 PRO ...)
```

However, when having Live USB in USB port, selecting boot devices from BIOS (Esc) produces the `set` output with `hd` numbers shifted by one:

```
error: symbol `grub_term_highlight_color` not found.
grub rescue> set
lang=
locale_dir=
prefix=(hd1,gpt6)/grub
root=hd1,gpt6
secondary_locale_dir=
```

and

```
error: file `/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod` not found.
grub rescue> set
prefix=(hd2,gpt6)/grub
root=hd2,gpt6
```

I feel this is OK, although not 100% sure it is not the reason for Win7 boot failing.

Here is the info from boot-repair: [Paste from boot-repair in pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25607049/).

I am afraid of running the boot-repair as its **Suggested repair** seems to be fixing the booting of Ubuntu, not that of Win. (I'm still to learn what `rename-ms-efi` means.)

I also had an idea to remove the SSD and to try booting with HDD only, but am afraid the EFI partition will be screwed even more (e.g. by auto-fixing itself) and I won't be able to boot to Ubuntu 14 anymore. Sounds stupid, probably. But after all, introducing Ubuntu 14 next to the original Win7 lead to grub not being able to resume Win7 from hibernation. So, I'm afraid of grub doing a "good job" again.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

I'll be creating back-ups for the SSD partitions in the meanwhile.

Comment: No, Win7 was installed in EFI mode, and so was Ubuntu 14. Grub could boot both Win7 and Ubuntu (12,13,14) until the SSD was added.

The Paste from Boot-repair shows that no partition is set in legacy mode. And /dev/sda1 partition was there already before installing Ubuntu for the very first time (Ubuntu 12, AFAIR). See line 151 in the [Paste from Boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25607049/).

Comment: Any install to drive other than sda installs /EFI/ubuntu into the ESP - efi system partition on sda. Chain entries need to refer to correct ESP.  It depends on how UEFI/BIOS enumerate drives. I also have same issue with DVD in grub as hd1 and sdb as hd2 on another system. Note that blkid's partUUID is GUID and used in UEFI as seen by efibootmgr -v. You show two Ubuntu entries one from each ESP. You need to make sure chain entry is to correct ESP to boot Windows. I might remove all search lines and just rely on set root, but you may have to experiment with hd0, or hd1 etc.

Comment: If EFI/ubuntu always gets installed to sda, then the only way to have it installed into the right drive is to temporarily remove all other drives before installing Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` after booted from any drive with all drives connected? Is it so? Anyway, many thanks, @oldfred ! Win7 now boots up and I've posted my own Answer of how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the hints, @oldfred !

I started digging into the chain entries and discovered that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` files differ on `sda` and `sdb`. The original `grub.cfg` from HDD (`sda`) contained the menu entry I used to boot into Win7, while the `grub.cfg` of `sdb` didn't have it. I don't remember if the custom menu entries were created by me or by grub upon installing Ubuntu 12 next to Win7. [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Chainloading_Windows.2FLinux_installed_in_UEFI_mode) and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Windows_installed_in_UEFI-GPT_Mode_menu_entry) could be helpful to others to create the custom menu entry manually.

Here are the 2 steps I did to make Win7 boot again:

1. Copy missing `/etc/grub.d/25_custom` over to `sdb` from `sda`.

The contents of `/etc/grub.d/25_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

menuentry "Windows UEFI bkpbootmgfw.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 40BE-2040
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bkpbootmgfw.efi
}

menuentry "Windows Boot UEFI loader" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 40BE-2040
chainloader (${root})/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}

menuentry "efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi" {
search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 84ba8463-a7a4-4a32-a429-f28e606435f2
chainloader (${root})/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
}
```

where `40BE-2040` and `84ba8463-a7a4-4a32-a429-f28e606435f2` are EFI partition and /boot partition of Ubuntu 14 on HDD, respectively:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="40BE-2040" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="41d1ad3d-8c17-44cd-9e4f-e6554d3c532b"
/dev/sda6: UUID="84ba8463-a7a4-4a32-a429-f28e606435f2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7f61e2e3-7b36-49a0-a357-90032497db30"
```

`sudo update-grub` then updates the `grub.cfg`.

To boot Win7 I'm using the 2nd menu entry: `Windows Boot UEFI loader`.

2. If your encrypted swap partition got broken, recover it by following these steps:
   punygeek.blogspot.com.ee/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html

The swap got broken in my case probably because of changing the name & label of EFI partition on `sdb` while investigating if non-unique partition name/label could be the cause for Win7 not booting. The swap partition started asking for password on Ubuntu 16 booting. I couldn't fix it by updating UUID in `/etc/fstab`, `/etc/crypttab` and `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`. Only the above link helped to fix the encrypted swap partition. Running `sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap` did fail, but after rebooting the swap got encrypted properly:

```
> lsblk
├─sdb3           8:19   0     8G  0 part  
│ └─cryptswap1 253:0    0     8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

And the output of `swapon -s` differs from shown in the above link:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   8388092 0   -1
```

But it seems it is the correct swap partition:

```
> ls -l /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 sept  25 14:02 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 -> ../dm-0
```